# target all browsers except IE if statement <!--[if !IE]> shows in FF

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am creating a template, and I have two different CSS styling sheets. One for IE and one for all other browsers.

I found a solution to target all browsers and IE browsers.

In my header I indicate:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--><link rel="stylesheet" href="path/templates/thisTemplate/css/the-pack.css" type="text/css" /><!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="path/templates/thisTemplate/css/template_ie_lt_9.css" type="text/css" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

The style sheets work fine. Except that firefox shows the text `<!--[if !IE]>` at the beginning of the page

Can you provide me with proper alternatives? Or why is this text showing, even though is in the head element, and what do I need to do for this not to show?

Thank you

Comment: Why not just make the main stylesheet for normal browsers default (no conditional), then only conditionally include the IE one. Normally my IE specific stylesheets only have a few styles in them, and if needed I use the !important tag to the override styles in the default stylesheet.

Comment: @antisanity how could I do this? Could you refer me to some documentation where I can learn about this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of a positive conditional comment is just `<![endif]-->`, do not restart a new comment:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet"
href="path/templates/thisTemplate/css/template_ie_lt_9.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I thought the same, but conditional comments seem to be more complex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment

Comment: @Tae This version is indubitably a correct comment for standard browsers, and it works in IE, so it's a valid conditional comment. I don't know where the more complex Wikipedia forms come from, but according to Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx#examples ), the Wikipedia version is incorrect.

Comment: thank you, this remove the unwanted text in firefox, and style sheets are loading as expected

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says:

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->
This code displays on non-IE browsers and on IE 7 or higher.
<!--<![endif]-->
```

So, maybe you should change `if !IE` with `if gt IE 9`?

More info: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be the code:

```
<!--[if !IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="path/templates/thisTemplate/css/the-pack.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="path/templates/thisTemplate/css/template_ie_lt_9.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

Greetz,

XpertEase

Answer (score 0):

An old question but more relevant than ever so another possible solution.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" media="(min-width:0px)">

<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

You can avoid conditionals by using the media attribute, this is not understood by older browsers so the file does not get loaded.